# YelpApi: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Missing"

Tags: javascript, react-native, yelp

I'm making a simple get request from the Yelp API and it works in the mobile version but for some reason, in REACct NATIVE it looks like it's not returning a JSON. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the error

```
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Missing"
* [native code]:null in parse
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

The code for the API call is this

**Yelp.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const apiKey = '8yC19Qb1LhfI5R7XXm65RoogEKVuq19uscnTP8Qppzij22Fa7m4rSF1W4SQD9Av9gLv4WyzSAx6YhWB3hsacVZxFYNXEb-8UwfFZc6yTOC28GOk4MO4350_1HmWLX3Yx'

const Yelp = {
    search(term){
        return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=calgary&sort_by=best_match`, 
        { headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}` 
          }})
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((jsonResponse) => {
                if (jsonResponse.businesses){
                    console.log(jsonResponse.businesses);
                    return jsonResponse.businesses.map((business) => {
                        return {
                            id: business.id,
                            imageSrc: business.image_url,
                            name: business.name,
                            address: business.location.address1,
                            city: business.location.city,
                            state: business.location.state,
                            zipCode: business.location.zip_code,
                            category: business.categories[0].alias,
                            rating: business.rating,
                            reviewCount: business.review_count,
                            url: business.url
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            
    }
}


module.exports = Yelp
```

And this is how I am colling it in my Search Bar and Search Screen

**SearchScreen.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import CardListings from '../components/CardListings'
import SearchBusiness from '../components/SearchBusiness'
import Yelp from '../api/yelp'

const Expensive = []
const Cheaper = []
const Cheap = []



export default function SearchScreen() {
    const [businesses, setBusineses] = useState([])
    const [isAddMode, setIsAddMode] = useState(false)

    const searchBusiness = () => {
        setIsAddMode(true)   
    }

    const handlePress = (term) => {
        Yelp.search(term)
            .then((businesses) => {
                setBusineses(businesses)
            })
        setIsAddMode(false)
    }
   
    

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            {/* <SearchBusiness setName={setBusineses} /> */}
            <Button title='Search here' onPress={searchBusiness}  />
            <SearchBusiness isAddMode={isAddMode} handleCancel={() => setIsAddMode(false)} handlePress={handlePress}/>
           <CardListings businesses={Expensive} type='Expensive'/>
           <CardListings businesses={Cheaper} type='Cheapest'/>
           <CardListings businesses={Cheap} type='Cheap'/>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        
    }
})
```

**SearchBar.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Modal, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export default function SearchBusiness(props) {
    const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('')

    const handleChange = e => {
        setSearchItem(e)
    }

    const handleSearch = () => {
        props.handlePress(searchItem)
        setSearchItem('')
    }


    return (

        <Modal
            animationType='slide'
            visible={props.isAddMode}

        >
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Enter Password '
                    autoCapitalize='sentences'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    value={searchItem}
                    onChangeText={handleChange}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={handleSearch} >
                    <Text style={styles.done} >Search</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnGhost} onPress={props.handleCancel} >
                    <Text style={styles.textGhost} >Cancel</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Modal>


    )

}
``
```

Comment: Can you post any errors that ouccred? Without specific errors it will be hard to determine where the problems are.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post so you should be able to see the error now

Comment: Try logging the response in the `then` handle and see the response value.